# How do I have a vue component with a ref apply it to a child?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that contains an input. When I put a ref on the component I want it to point to the input. Is this possible?

```vue
Vue.component('input-icon', {
    props: ['value', 'icon'],
    template: `
        <span class="input-icon flex-container">
            <span class="icon-container vertical-center" @click="icon_click" :class="{'icon-click': is_icon_click}">
                <i class="material-icons">{{icon}}</i>
            </span>
            <input ref="input" type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" class="full-flex text-left" v-bind="$attrs">
            <span class="clear" @click="clear"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></span>
        </span>
    `,
    methods: {
        icon_click(e) {if (this.is_icon_click) this.$emit('button-click', e)},
        clear() {
            this.value = '';
            this.$refs.input.focus();
        }
    },
    computed: {
        is_icon_click() {return !!this._events['button-click']}
    }
});
```

```html
<input-icon ref="search_bar" icon="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search"></input-icon>
```

EDIT: I am aware that I can use `this.$refs.search_bar.$refs.input` but it's ugly. Just hoping for a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the input within the input-icon component. Create a method within the input-icon component that returns the input ref.

That is a cleaner way in my opinion